# Extracting data from excel pivot tables using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table, xlsx, openpyxl

I'm working with XLSX files with pivot tables and writing an automated script to parse and extract the data. I have multiple pivot tables per spreadsheet with cost categories, their totals, and their values for each month etc. Any ideas on how to use openpyxl to parse each pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible with openpyxl.